# Replace SerializeField with a static Instance in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Normally I would call a method from another Monobehaviour this way

```
[SerializeField]
private OtherScript s;

private void Start()
{
    s.DoSomething();
}
```

And I thought about something like this

```
public class OtherScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static OtherScript Instance { get { return this; } }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Debug.Log("Call");
    }
}
```

Then I could call the method from other scripts this way

```
OtherScript.Instance.DoSomething();
```

But I can't return `this` as a static property. The workaround would be this

```
public class OtherScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static OtherScript instance;

    public static OtherScript Instance { get { return instance; } }

    private void Start()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Debug.Log("Call");
    }
}
```

When using this code some problems may appear because the Instance is set in the `Start` method. This might be too late if other components need the reference while executing their own `Start` method.

All monobehaviours that are unique like `GameManager`, `GameObserver`, `IngameMenu`, etc. should have a static instance because they only exist once in the scene and I don't have to setup a inspector field for this reference multiple times.

Is there a better way using a static instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When using this code some problems may appear because the Instance is
>   set in the Start method. This might be too late if other components
>   need the reference while executing their own Start method

True but that's why we have the `Awake` function. Set initialize it the `Awake` function the read it in the `Start` function. The `Awake` function will be called on every script before `Start` is called.

```
public class OtherScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static OtherScript instance;

    public static OtherScript Instance { get { return instance; } }

    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Debug.Log("Call");
    }
}
```

The rest of your code should remain the-same.

Comment: but `Awake` does not have a 100% guarantee being called before `Start` right?

Comment: 100% guaranteed. Scroll to the bottom of the page to see the execution flowchart [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) which is even documented.

Comment: thanks a lot, I think it's way more useful than having many inspector fields multiple times